# Зависание MonoDevelop

Tags: linux-mint, gtk, monodevelop

Зависает MonoDevelop в режиме создания приложения gtk на c# при попытке добавить на кнопку картинку через свойства. Как это поправить?
Система Linux Mint 19.1 64bit

Comment: MonoDevelop в целом багнутая

Comment: А чем можно пользоваться? И чё с этим делать теперь?

Comment: я пользуюсь jetbrains rider, однако он платный, есть trial 30 дней

Comment: да так-то вопросов нет, да моно нужен в идеале. но чёт я походу разрабатывать начну на C++ или Java. Благо ничего ещё толком не начато...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что проблема никак не исправляется подручными средствами. Принято решение работать с разработчиками MonoDevelop.